# Can you display a PhoneGap app as a Screencast in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-devtools

Can't find an answer to this anywhere.

We have a prototype PhoneGap app that we deploy to Android devices. Using Chrome Developer tools we can debug it using the normal tools edit CSS etc and it will change the display on the device.

This is all great but I was wondering is there a way to use the screencast tool that displays your phone screen within developer tools for a phonegap app. From what I can tell it on;y seems to be able to pick up sites open in Chrome on the android device.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screencasting of WebViews is not supported at this time.

Maybe it's not exactly what you are looking for, but it helped me when troubleshooting:
Depending on the toolset you are using, you can try to access your local webserver on your development machine from the chrome browser on your android device. For this to work, the phone must be in your network (Wi-Fi).

I'm developing a PhoneGap app using Visual Studio and configured my environment to allow access from remote computers, see this [blog post](http://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/allowing-remote-access-to-your-iis-express-service/).

I also ran this command for my 'web site', found on the [blog of Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>IisExpressAdminCmd.exe 
setupFriendlyHostnameUrl -url:http://yourcomputername:555/
```

Finally I was able to use the Screencasting feature, using the chrome browser from android.
Except that I was not able to use hardware features such as NFC, using the app via the browser felt the same.

For other environments, the procedure to enable remote access should be similar.

Martin